# List of useful sources for Skeptics.SE

Tags: discussion, references, citations

The goal of this post is to contain a long number of sources, sorted by topic, to help users find sources for their answers. It's Community Wiki so that everyone can edit add new sources.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Reliable sources

The following are sources that are accepted as valid sources to justify your statements, sorted by category. It is by no means an exhaustive list of the accepted sources.

### General

- [The Cochrane Collaboration](http://www.cochrane.org/cochrane-reviews): Systematic reviews across a broad range of topics.

### Environment

- [Environmental Science & Technology](http://pubs.acs.org/journal/esthag): Peer-reviewed journal in environmental science.
- [Environment Canada](http://www.ec.gc.ca/default.asp?lang=en)
- [Fuel Economy](http://www.fueleconomy.gov/): The official U.S. government source for fuel economy.
- [United States Environmental Agency](http://www.epa.gov/)

### Government statistics

- [Australia](http://www.ands.org.au/)
- [Canada](http://www.data.gc.ca/)
- [Google Public Data](http://www.google.com/publicdata/directory)
- [United States](http://www.data.gov/)
- [United Kingdom](http://data.gov.uk/)
- [World Bank](http://data.worldbank.org/)

### Health

- [Food and Drug Agency](http://www.fda.gov/)
- [JAMA Topic Collection](http://jama.ama-assn.org/cgi/collection/): Browse Journal of AMA published research by topic
- [Health Canada](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/index-eng.php)
- [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/)

## Other sources

The following are sources that are not deemed reliable enough to justify a statement but still are amazingly useful sources, sorted by category. It is by no means an exhaustive list.

### General

- [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/): Open access to 662,023 e-prints in Physics, Mathematics, Computer Science, Quantitative Biology, Quantitative Finance and Statistics.
- [Dr Karl](http://www.abc.net.au/science/drkarl/greatmomentsinscience/)
- [Google Books](http://books.google.com/)
- [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/): Google's search engine of peer-reviewed literature. Peer reviewed literature that can be found with the tool is generally reliable, but please don't point to google scholar result pages as sources.
- [JREF Forums](http://forums.randi.org/)
- Mythbusters
- [MythBusters Results](http://mythbustersresults.com/)
- [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/)
- [Straight dope](http://www.straightdope.com/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)

### Health

- [Science-Based Medicine](http://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/)

### Economics

- [Worthwhile Canadian Initiative](http://worthwhile.typepad.com/): Canadian economics blog by several Canadian university professors
- [The Tax Protester FAQ](http://evans-legal.com/dan/tpfaq.html): A large collection of debunked pseudo-legal arguments used by so-called 'tax protestors' in court.  Sharing much in common with pseudo-science, this body of pseudo-law is often as imaginative as it is absurd.

### Environment

- [Global Warming & Climate Change Myths](http://www.skepticalscience.com/argument.php): Long list of refutations of common argument against climate change

Comment: I think a disclaimer should be added for arxiv. They allow many self-published non peer reviewed papers, so it isn't necessarily a reputable source.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: That's why arxiv is under "other sources" rather than under reliable sources.

Comment: @Borror0 Ahh of course, I'm not sure how I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: What is wrong with google scholar and books - they provide access to scholarly books and peer reviewed atricles

Comment: Google Scholar contains most scientific publication. I fail to see how it can be classified as "Other sources"

Comment: Not all that is in google scholar is peer reviewed. Also, google scholar result pages are not sources in themselves.

Comment: I see skeptics.SE isn't listed here...