# Is Wikipedia a valid source?

Tags: discussion, answers, citations

For most professional citations, Wikipedia is frowned upon, but [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20474/18134) defies all of those conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's case-by-case. If you try to use Wikipedia as a reference and get challenged, you'll have to go deeper and follow the references to come up with your own summary of the situation.

Wikipedia will likely be accepted as a source in an answer when:

- [linking to a permanent link](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Permanent_link&oldid=547695477) for a particular version of a page, so that future edits don't change the content of the reference,
- when the material contained in the Wikipedia article/section is well-sourced itself,
- when using the Wikipedia reference simply to [establish the meaning of some technical or jargon term](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/973/5582) for lay-readers,
- repeating the references from Wikipedia in your answer if the material from Wikipedia is essential to the answer here, or if the material is contentious.

(Those rules-of-thumb are my best guesses based on what I think I've observed here over the past year... could be subject to failed memory, confirmation bias, etc.)

I did this in [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/20464/5582). I liked the sentence and wanted to use it, so I needed to cite Wikipedia.

Regarding the specific question you're asking about, it *would* be improved if it linked to a permanent link. Other than that, apparently nobody has found the answer  contentious or likely to change over time with new evidence, so it's been well-received here.