# How to do my own research

Tags: discussion

This is almost a meta question, but I think that it's interesting and valid for the main site.

Given a particular topic (for example: *Is the Alexander Technique valid, or just snake oil?*), where do I start researching it myself, as opposed to just asking the question here?

Please help me educate myself!

Comment: It's not almost a meta question, it's exactly a meta question. We even have a few similar ones in meta.

Comment: @Kit, well I'll bow to the community's take on that. I *don't* think it's a meta question about `skeptics.se`, it's a meta question about scepticism.

Comment: @Benjol - `skeptics.SE` isn't about skepticism as a subject, but rather about applying skepticism. (Newcomers are often rightfully confused about that). As such the only on-topic questions are those that are trying to analyze a specific claim. If you are posing a question about how you would go about analyzing a claim, then that would be a meta-applying-skepticism question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the best places to start is [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/), on which you can search many [peer-reviewed academic publications](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2992/do-peer-reviewed-journals-enhance-the-quality-of-scientific-research) from a wide variety of disciplines (*e.g.*, medicine, engineering, psychology, sociology, economics, *&c.*).  For example, a number of promising results pop up when [searching for "Alexander Technique validity"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Alexander%20Technique%20validity&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0,21&as_ylo=&as_vis=0):

- [*Randomized controlled trial of the Alexander technique for idiopathic Parkinson's disease*](http://cre.sagepub.com/content/16/7/695.short);
- [*An evaluation of the Alexander Technique for the management of disability in Parkinson's disease- a preliminary study*](http://cre.sagepub.com/content/11/1/8.short); and
- [*Functional reach improvement in normal older women after Alexander Technique instruction*](http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/54/1/M8.short).

Unfortunately, many of the full text articles will be behind a [paywall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paywall), however,

1. if you happen to be browsing from a University's network, you will often automatically get access to the paid content since most Universities buy subscriptions to the content;
2. you will always be able to get the abstract to the article for free, which often includes the relevant information (*e.g.*, what experiments were performed and a summary of the results); and
3. one can often find a free version of an article that is behind a paywall by [searching for its title on "regular" Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Comparison%20of%20Straining%20During%20Defecation%20in%20Three%20Positions:%20Results%20and%20Implications%20for%20Human%20Health) (in some disciplines, authors often post a free version of the article on their personal website).

Comment: Excellent stuff! Now off to try it out... (I still think this level of 'educational' content is valuable for the main site)

Comment: Google Scholar can show all places where it found the document ("show x versions"), sometimes one of those is a free one.

Comment: One cave at with Google Scholar: It is not that the search engine actually knows that these are peer-reviewed papers. It searches for documents having the outside appearance of published scientific work, but you can just as well get links from the Discovery Institute (a creationist propaganda think-tank). You still have to make sure you don't get junk, but at least your search is more focused than just plain google.

Comment: @Lagerbaer good point.

Answer (score 2):

We're compiling a list of good sources in [List of useful sources for Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/list-of-useful-sources-for-skeptics-se), which may help you. It's Community Wiki, so feel free to add more to it if you see any good sources missing from the list.