# is Skeptics for specific claims only, or about learning about skepticism?

Tags: discussion

I didn't see a tag for *research* or other terms I tried.  Can I ask how do you research claims via search engines if the sites I know about like Snopes doesn't have it?  I won't go into it further since this is a meta-sandbox not the sandboxed question itself yet.

Answer (score 2):

Skeptics.SE is not directly aimed at teaching or discussing skepticism. (Although they are common topics in the chat and on Meta.Skeptics.SE)

Skeptics.SE is about *applying* scientific skepticism - researching the evidence to support or refute commonly heard/believed claims.

Snopes is just one, limited, source of information. It is often a secondary or tertiary source, rather than a primary source.

Some other sources include [these](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/list-of-useful-sources-for-skeptics-se).

I hope this answered your question; it wasn't entirely clear.